# need to use HTML's tag MAP in joomla site

Tags: php

I need to use Map HTML tag to make my image work as hyperlink, linked to different social sites, but map tag is not working in Joomla!, but it was working in HTML site.

This is the code I'm using

```
<img src="images/social_media_icons.jpg" border="0" alt="social media icons" width="365" height="44" /> <map id="Map" name="Map"> 
<area shape="rect" coords="18,6,56,39" href="twitter_Link" target="_blank" />

<area shape="rect" coords="77,6,112,39" href="facebook_Link" target="_blank" />

<area shape="rect" coords="191,6,229,38" href="youtube_link" target="_blank" />

 </map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed the editor and this work for me :)
used JCE Editor for joomla